# How to round any number with a decimal point up to next number twig

Tags: twig

I need to be able to take any number and if it has number after the decimal round it up.  I am pretty new to twig and I am struggling with this a bit.

Right now I have

```
{{ 20.1|round(0) }}
```

Which rounds down here because it is under.5, however in this instance I would still need to round up.  Is there a function for this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer shortly after.

```
{{ 20.1|round(0,'ceil') }}
```